# Sharpe Ratio and interest rate

Tags: sharpe-ratio, interest, ratio

The Sharpe ratio is calculated as the ratio between the return and the volatility.

Now, when I have a trading strategy that requires to be invested sometimes and to be flat other times, I assume  0% during the flat time. This results in 9.5% average annualized return and 9.6% annualized standard deviation. I could compute the Sharpe ratio simply by the ratio of the two. Now I have the option to add a coupon that yields 2% during the flat time. Is it then correct to add the 2% to the return, so the Sharpe ratio grows?

Comment: The way you compute return should mirror your implementation. If during the "flat" periods, you'll be putting the cash to use and earn that 2%, then yes you should include it in your strategy's total return calculation.

Comment: Correct what Helin says, but you should also compare to the return of a benchmark, otherwise does not show any performance over naive strategies, and that is the real purpose of Sharpe ratio